# how to use `webpack.ProvidePlugin` with 'ec6 import` syntax on webpack 2

Tags: javascript, plugins, webpack-2

Webpack 2.0 support `import` and `require` syntax natively so in whole project i don't need to use `bable.js` at all .

But now I try to use `webpack.ProvidePlugin` and do something like that :

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    '$': [require('../src/utils/dom'),'$']
})
```

`dom.js` writed ec6 style and at head of the file there is line like:

```
export let $  = document.querySelector.bind(document);
```

and Webpack's plugin throw exception :

```
 export let $  = document.querySelector.bind(document);
 ^^^^^^
 SyntaxError: Unexpected token export
```

Comment: Maybe try `export default let $ = document.querySelector.bind(document);`

Comment: ok, I tried it still not work

Comment: Does it work if you remove the plugin? And try to import the module normally?

Comment: yes, of course. that plugin is kind of refactoring to existing code

Comment: Then you may still need babel if the plugin doesn't support es2015.

Comment: I try using syntax like that: `require('bable-loader!../src/utils/dom')`. but it say bable loader not exist ( but it exist , I have very well configuration bable inside the project, that I disabled because it not really necessity